# .profile not running when I start a bash terminal

Tags: bash, .profile

When I start a bash terminal, my .profile is not being executed. I do not have a ~/.bash_profile or a ~/.bash_login, so .profile is supposed to run, right? What else could be wrong?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's not a login shell.

If a shell is a login shell, it will look for .bash_profile if it exists, then .profile.
Other shells look for .bashrc

So, you can put the things you want in every shell instance in .bashrc, and possibly have a reference that sources .bashrc in .profile.

So:
.bashrc:

```
stuff you want
```

end of .profile:

```
[ -n "$BASH" ] && [ -f ~/.bashrc ] && . ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: So when I run 'konsole' in KDE, that is a non-login shell, right? On another machine I have definitely put things in .profile and had them work when I open a terminal like this - I guess I don't understand when you'd want something different to happen at login vs when you open a terminal?

Comment: @DavidDoria it depends, I have changed configs or made aliases to what konsole runs, to make it run `bash --login`. In your case it seems to just run bash, which by default will not trigger a login shell

Comment: If you are using LightDM that might be the reason. Other display managers like GDM and KDM source .profile on login, but LightDM does not (by design). See http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=636108

Comment: I am using KDM.

Comment: If you are using Gnome Terminal, you can do Edit->Profile Preferences, go to the Title and Command tab, and check "Run command as a login shell". It will then source your .bash_profile or .profile whenever you open a terminal, as expected.

Comment: ~/.bashrc is the place instead of ~/.profile add your data to ~/.bashrc for terminal to pick up in non-login mode. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

try using `~/.bashrc` instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a graphical desktop, .profile should be sourced by your desktop manager. Lightdm *does* source .profile now, at least on Ubuntu.  See: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/794315

With kdm, and Kubuntu-12.04, the file /etc/kde4/kdm/Xsession gets sourced, which does the .profile including.  Kubuntu-12.10 will probably use lightdm.  Ubuntu 12.04 uses lightdm so that /usr/sbin/lightdm-session sources .profile.

I think the way to go is to (1) set/export environment settings in ~/.profile and (2) have .profile sourced by .bash_profile:

```
[[ -f ~/.profile ]] && . ~/.profile
```

(and not have .bashrc sourced by either .profile or .bash_profile).

See also:

- Setting the BROWSER environment variable in .profile: http://fvue.nl/wiki/Linux:_Default_browser

Comment: This explains how to get your `.profile` sourced at login, but he's actually wondering about how to get `bash` to source it when he launches a terminal (not at login)

Comment: You shouldn't want to have .profile sourced when you launch a new terminal (from within KDE).  The whole purpose of .profile is to have it sourced once at login, either on a graphical terminal or a text terminal; .profile should've been sourced the moment you logged into KDE.

Comment: *.profile should be sourced by your desktop manager.*  Well this depends on understanding of the file's purpose.  In Debian, /etc/profile (and ~/.profile as its extension) [is meant to be for bash-like shells](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=636108).

Comment: You don't need to source it again IF its sourced at login. your bash will inherit it unless you're doing something silly like "export PATH=~/.bin" or something causing it to be overwritten.