# Why doesn't my terminal load .profile when I launch it?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, terminal, .profile

I am very new to being a developer, and I have just started using Ubuntu. I am currently trying to run elasticbeanstalk CLI on my terminal, but I always get "eb: command not found" error when I type "eb" into the terminal. I can only get it to work if I type in "source ~/.profile" after I start my terminal.

As far as I can tell, I have followed the installation guide pretty closely.  My guess is that .profile isn't loaded every time I start the terminal. Is there anyway I can fix/automate this? .bash_profile and .bash_login doesn't exist on home directory, so I don't think that is interfering.

I'm also not familiar with terms like bash, gnome etc, would help if you guys are able to explain in a not-so-technical way.

Comment: [Bash and Its Startup File Execution Algorithm](https://savage.net.au/Linux/html/bash.files.html)

Comment: [Shell initialization files](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_01.html)

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/385766/profile-not-running-when-i-start-a-bash-terminal?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile is the login script and is *not supposed to be* loaded for every interactive shell, only by the initial 'login' shell (if one exists). It's a good place to set session-wide environment variables or run one-time things.

To define aliases or set other shell-internal parameters, you should use `~/.bashrc` instead.

(Note, you can't avoid having a `source ~/.bashrc` at the end of your ~/.bash_profile, because due to historical reasons the same 'login' shell that reads profile scripts actually doesn't read ~/.bashrc by default.)